# Domain class not found in grails-app/domain

Tags: grails, scaffolding, grails-controller

With Grails 2.3.4, and scaffold 2.0.1; no object appears in the `index`(list) page of the controllers. The views are being automatically created by grails official scaffolding plugin.

I'm positive there actually are objects added, since when creating a object that needs another, the latter appears as an option in the former's creation page.

What appears is the "main" layout and an empty table that would contain the actual data.

One example of a domain class(Bairro) that doesn't appear in it's controller `index` action (which is the data listing) .

```
package webservice.web

class Bairro {
    String nome

    static belongsTo = [cidade:Cidade]

    static constraints = {
        nome(nullable:false, maxSize:30)
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return nome
    }
}
```

and it's controller

```
package siscoserv.web

class BairroController {

    def index() { }
    static scaffold = true
}
```

and here is the list of installed plugins

```
 plugins {
        build ":tomcat:7.0.47"

        compile ":scaffolding:2.0.1"
        compile ':cache:1.1.1'

        runtime ":hibernate:3.6.10.6" // or ":hibernate4:4.1.11.6"
        runtime ":database-migration:1.3.8"
        runtime ":jquery:1.10.2.2"
        runtime ":resources:1.2.1"
        runtime ":database-migration:1.3.8"
        runtime ":yui-minify-resources:0.1.5"
 }
```

Thanks

PS: Clarification: No controller works on this action page. I have created 4 similar domain classes and it's respective controllers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem could be that you are overriding default index action - try just this:

```
class BairroController {  
    static scaffold = true
}
```

Comment: yep, that was it. I'm not sure why I didn't try that. Thanks