# Error domain class not found

Tags: macos, grails, osx-yosemite

I am able to create app using (`$ grails create-app MyDomain`) but not able to move forward with `$ grails generate-all MyDomain`.

> I made sure that I do have the domain generated with the proper name/spelling (by going physically
>   into the local folder on my machine), all looks ok. The only log I get
>   is the error message that says **Error domain class not found**
>   ...that's all. I am relatively new to grails. I am following exactly as
>   it instructs in [Dzone Refcardz for Grails](http://refcardz.dzone.com/refcardz/getting-started-grails)

There are two related questions on SO but they do not have answer for my question.

[Domain class not found in grails-app/domain](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21386700/domain-class-not-found-in-grails-app-domain)

[Grails 3.x: Re-using JPA/Hibernate Domain classes: Domain class not found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29908232/grails-3-x-re-using-jpa-hibernate-domain-classes-domain-class-not-found)

The only other doubt I've is: I have two versions of jdk on my osx (yosemite). I have set to use one in my profile. But I am not sure. As per my reading on the web, having two JDKs this **shouldn't** cause the error with `$ grails generate-all MyDomain`.

Is there any other avenues I should be looking at to resolve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess that's the typical 'no package provided while creating a domain class' problem. By default, if you omit the package name e.g. if you just create a domain class `$ grails create-app MyDomain` the MyDomain.groovy file is created under the `app-name` package i.e. `MyApplication.MyDomain`.

If that's the case then your `$ grails generate-all MyDomain` should actually be `$ grails generate-all MyApplication.MyDomain`.